# How to add a google font api in magento admin panel

Tags: email, html-email, magento2, webfonts, google-webfonts

I am working on editing email templates in the Magento 2 Admin Panel. I am trying to add Montserrat, a google font, to the email templates. Magento doesn't recognize the google font api and won't include the font.

I have tried adding the below code lines in the html file under the head tag but this provides me with a 404 error.

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 

<link src="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" src_type="url">
```

I have flushed the cache and still no luck.  I've changed the text from a `<p>` tag to `<span>`, and still nothing. I also tried entering

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,800&display=swap");
```

in the template styles section and this doesn't work.

Example code:

```
<p style="margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box;font-family:'Montserrat', sans-serif;"> Hello </p>
```

I expect the font to be Montserrat, but instead we get sans-serif.

Comment: What is the location of the file that you edited? 
it should in /layout/default_head_blocks.xml.
see https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#layout_markup_css
on how to add css

Comment: I am customizing the email templates using Magento Admin. Was wondering if there is a way to fix it through this rather than through .xml https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-email.html

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Web fonts have very limited support in emails. The following email clients will render _Montserrat_ properly: `iOS Mail, Apple Mail, Android (default mail client, not Gmail app), Outlook 2000, Outlook.com app and Thunderbird`. You will need to define a fallback font. If not defined they will read their default font (times new roman mostly for Outlook).